# What can this C preprocessor macro mapping to a C keyword be used for?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, keyword

I found this line in a legacy code and I'm wondering what is it good for. Do you have any idea?

```
#define CONST const
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes macros like that are used to be able to compile the code with older compilers that may not support all features.

For instance, in this case, you could simply define `CONST` as empty, which would allow you to compile the code in a very old C compiler without support for the `const` qualifier.

You will typically see macros like this in implementations of the standard libraries.

---

There is another common, related case of macros that map to C keywords: to be able to introduce [new C keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword) in newer C Standards without breaking old code. These standard macros are added for usage convenience, e.g. the `bool` macro defined in `stdbool.h` for the [`_Bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/_Bool) keyword.

Comment: To add to this, it is also done sometimes for settings to be edited pre-compile although that is not very good practice

Comment: Unfortunately I saw that people are doing something like this just because they think `CONST` looks better than `const`...